# Can I unite react and webapi in single asp net core 5 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have made one webapi project.
Now I am trying to make project react project for another task. For testing I want split project in two parts ui and sever with api. I started add code from webapi project to react project (with such changes as renaming classes, interfaces, fields etc). But api controller is not working and swagger fails.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TaskList
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            services.AddDbContext<ITaskRepository,TaskContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connection));

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TaskList", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TaskList v1"));
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
class TaskController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ITaskRepository _repository;

    public TaskController(ITaskRepository r)
    {
        _repository = r;
    }

    [Route("GetAll")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<SheduledTask>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _repository.GetAll();
    }

    [Route("GetUnfineshedTasksEndingBefore")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<SheduledTask>> GetUnfineshedTasksEndingBefore(DateTime t)
    {
        return await _repository.GetUnfineshedTasksEndingBefore(t);
    }

    public class CreateParams
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public DateTime Begin {get; set;}
        public DateTime End {get; set;}
    }

    [Route("Create")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async  Task<SheduledTask> Create(CreateParams p)
    {
        return await _repository.Create(p.Name, p.Begin, p.End);
    }

    [Route("SetFinished")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<SheduledTask> SetFinished(string id)
    {
        return await _repository.SetFinished(id);
    }
}
```

[Swagger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lD9B.jpg)

[API request result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfVeq.jpg)

All code in github: https://github.com/al-al-se/TaskList

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by it is not working, perhaps provide an example of Api Controller setup and attempt to use it.  there is nothing in this Startup that looks abnormal or unexpected.  do you have launcherSettings.json setup for swagger (in properties)?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.. I have no issues running spa and swagger in .NET Core WebApi project that targets net5. note: swagger does have a dependency package and is accessed at `<host>/swagger/`.   I presume `ApiController` is working, but your basing 'not working' off of doing some react app workflow (like fetch weatherforecast for example - which results in 401 unauthorized response in my example without a scope claim being present... which is expected)...

Comment: Swagger return: openapi "3.0.1"
info 
title "TaskList"
version "v1"
paths {}
components {}

Comment: API request https://localhost:5001/Task/GetAll return blank page with header from react

Comment: question was updated

Comment: what is the response status code of that Task/GetAll request? 200, 500?  i.e. are you not catching any exceptions while debugging? put a break point on the first line in GetAll and do the request again.  do you have scheduledtask data to return there?  it's also possible that the issue here relates to the construction of TaskRepository as it relates to Entity Framework Dependency Injection.  Also, Do you have Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package in this project?